# Resetting a FaceBook App Domain and Web Platform URL - Possible Caching issue?

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, facebook-apps, facebook-app-settings

I have an app where currently the App Domain is set to *www.site1.co.uk* as is the Web Platform URL. I use Login with Facebook and Register with Facebook via this app. Client OAuth Login and Web OAuth Login are enabled for this app. There are no Valid OAuth redirect URIs stored.

I need to change this to *www.site2.co.uk*.  If I change both the App Domain and Web Platform URL to www.site2.co.uk and then go to the website www.site2.co.uk and click on the login withFacebook button I still get the error stating that the url is not permitted by the application settings as it doesn't match the website URL. The Login as Facebook button still works on www.site1.co.uk at this point.

Are these values cached? If so how may I clear them please?

Also will changing these URLS mean that users who have previously registered or logged in via the www.site1.co.uk domain need to re-register etc from www.site2.co.uk or will they be able to continue to access the app via the new url unaffected?

This question/answer ([Does changing the Site URL/Domain of a Facebook App affect your users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913600/does-changing-the-site-url-domain-of-a-facebook-app-affect-your-users)) suggests that pre-existing users will not be affected but it IS quite old.

Any help gratefully received.
Many Thanks
Liz

Comment: There might be a bit of a delay, before your changed app settings are propagated to all servers in the FB network. (Make sure it actually _saved_ the settings though – if there is an error in your settings, they might not have been.) // Changing URLs will not affect your users – logins are tied to an app based on the app id, not on settings such as the domain.

Comment: Thanks for coming back so quickly CBroe. That's very helpful. Much appreciated.